# Program is failing when extern const is assigned with new value without any error. Need explanation regarding this

Tags: c++, extern

I have a extern const int variable in main.cpp which I am using in mathFunctions.cpp. If I try to modify the variable in mathFunctions.cpp, the program is failing.
I am using latest verion of CodeBlocks with C++ 11.

Program works fine if I do not try to modify the variable.

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern const int valueTen = 10;
int addValue(int);
int main()
{
    cout << addValue(2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
//mathFunctions.cpp
extern int valueTen;
int addValue(int x){
    valueTen++; //program stops because of this line
    return x + valueTen;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to modify a `const` variable?  Do you know what `const` means/does?

Comment: Yes, I do. As I am new to CPP, I am trying to understand the errors I will get in such cases.

Comment: _I am trying to understand the errors I will get in such cases._ You will get "the program is failing".

Comment: Very true. But in the IDE I am getting Process Terminated, but no proper error indicating why it is terminating.

Comment: It's because you lied to the compiler.  When you lie, you get in trouble (at least some of the times).

Comment: often you dont get errors when you do something wrong, in the best case something wrong happens, in the worst case it appears to be fine, until you try to show the program to your teacher/prof/customer

Comment: Unrelated: `extern` says "This is a  declaration of a variable. The actual variable will be defined elsewhere." If you tack on an initialization, as `extern const int valueTen = 10;` does, you get a definition instead of the declaration. The `extern` goes away, and sometimes it goes away silently. This can lead to problems later, so don't use `extern` with initialization.

Comment: @ user4581301: https://www.learncpp.com is my mentor and didn't find the point you mentioned yet.But I will keep this in mind. Thank you.

Comment: The C and C++ are still close enough in behaviour for this to be good reading: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files). Here is some good [documentation on `extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and also [on initialization in general](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). The latter two links are pretty low level and will probably take a read or two to translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile your `main.cpp` file, the statement `extern const int valueTen = 10;` tells the compiler that the `valueTen` variable is a constant, and will not be changed during run-time. Typically, this will 'pass on' a signal to the linker that it can allocate space for that variable in an area of memory with the `READONLY` attribute.

When you compile your `mathFunctions.cpp` file, the statement `extern int valueTen;` tells the compiler that `valueTen` is an integer variable, whose definition is provided by another module. In this file, there is nothing telling the compiler that `valueTen` is `const`, so you don't get a compiler error when you include code that modifies its value.

However, when you have built the program (linked all the individual modules), then the code produced by the `valueTen++;` statement will try to modify something that is located in `READONLY` memory - and this will cause the program to crash, with a message along the lines of "Access violation."

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! for the explanation.